# Number of Overlapping datetime(s)

Tags: vba, excel, date, date-range

I have two columns of date/time(s) and need to find out how many of them overlap at a particular time.

Use case is this: These are start and end times for phone calls and am looking to find the number of simultaneous calls.

```
Column A            Column B    
8/06/15 00:17:59    8/06/15 00:19:21     
8/09/15 00:21:06    8/09/15 00:22:06     
8/09/15 00:21:21    8/09/15 00:22:43     
8/09/15 00:22:11    8/09/15 00:22:46     
8/10/15 00:24:28    8/10/15 00:24:51
```

Expected Result:

```
Column A            Column B             Number Overlap    
8/06/15 00:17:59    8/06/15 00:19:21     0
8/09/15 00:21:06    8/09/15 00:22:06     1
8/09/15 00:21:21    8/09/15 00:22:43     2
8/09/15 00:22:11    8/09/15 00:22:46     1
8/10/15 00:24:28    8/10/15 00:24:51     0
```

The formula I am trying is this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A$2:A$35006<=B2)*(B$2:B$35006>=A2))
```

I would also like to reference similar questions, that do not quite answer what I need here, but have helped me get this far:

[Find number of concurrent, overlapping, date ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19596982/find-number-of-concurrent-overlapping-date-ranges/19608892#19608892)

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/388376-count-number-date-ranges-overlap-other-date-ranges.html

Comment: Will you need to look for those that have a complete overlap? So they start before another one and end after that one.

Comment: yes.  Anything that overlaps.  Basically, how many are happening at the same time.

Comment: Answer is updated to catch complete overlaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to subtract one from your current formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A$2:A$35006<=B2)*(B$2:B$35006>=A2))-1
```

Comment: I can't seem to get it working though,  all results come back as 0.

Comment: It's working here. It assumes your phone call times begin in row 2 and go down from there as far as row 35006. You must make sure that none of the entries are actually TEXT instead of true numbers.

Comment: If you like, I am available to help. Just send me the file and I'll have it sorted quickly. My email address is: daniel.ferry@gmail.com

Comment: I now recognize that there was a flaw in the way I asked this question.  Where it says "2" it should only say "1" as there is only one overlap at a time.. Yes, there are two records that overlap it, but they do not cross.

Comment: Please ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have VBA in you tags, here is how you can do it.

In you VBA IDE go to the tools menu and selecte references. Select "Microstoft ActiveX data objects 2.8 Library.

```
Private Sub CheckOverlaps()
    Dim ws1 As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim iCount As Integer
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim lRow As Long

    'Set the worksheet that you want to process by name
    Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    'Add fields to your recordset for storing data.
    With rs
        .Fields.Append "Row", adInteger
        .Fields.Append "Start", adDate
        .Fields.Append "End", adDate
        .Open
    End With

    lRow = 1

    ws1.Activate
    'Loop through and record what is in the columns
    Do While lRow <= ws1.UsedRange.Rows.count

        If ws1.Range("A" & lRow).Value <> "" Then
            rs.AddNew
            rs.Fields("Row").Value = lRow
            rs.Fields("Start").Value = ws1.Range("A" & lRow).Value
            rs.Fields("End").Value = ws1.Range("B" & lRow).Value
            rs.Update
        End If

        lRow = lRow + 1
        ws1.Range("A" & lRow).Activate
    Loop

    lRow = 1

    'Loop through and check for overlaps in the records.
    Do While lRow <= ws1.UsedRange.Rows.count

        iCount = 0

        If ws1.Range("A" & lRow).Value <> "" And ws1.Range("A" & lRow).Value <> "" Then

            'Check for those that started in the timespan
            rs.Filter = ""
            rs.Filter = "Start >= '" & ws1.Range("A" & lRow).Value & "' AND Start <='" & ws1.Range("B" & lRow).Value & "'"
            iCount = rs.RecordCount

            'Check for those that ended in the timespan
            rs.Filter = ""
            rs.Filter = "End >= '" & ws1.Range("A" & lRow).Value & "' AND End <='" & ws1.Range("B" & lRow).Value & "'"
            iCount = iCount + rs.RecordCount

            'Check for those that started before and ended after the current timespan.
            rs.Filter = ""
            rs.Filter = "Start <= '" & ws1.Range("A" & lRow).Value & "' AND End >='" & ws1.Range("B" & lRow).Value & "'"
            iCount = iCount + rs.RecordCount

            'Report the number. You minus three because the records that are the time will get counted each time
            ws1.Range("c" & lRow).Value = iCount - 3
        End If

        lRow = lRow + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```